# Not able to set text in a Text Area

Tags: watir

I was unable to set text into the text area with `browser.text_field(:id,"area").set "1=1"`. When i typed manually i noticed that the text("1=1") i typed is stored across spans as given below.

```
<pre>
<span class="number">1</span> # the text 1 is stored here and followed by "=1" in next spans
<span class="operator">=</span>
<span class="number">1</span>
</pre>
```

Is there any other way that i can set text into the text area?

Comment: Please provide link to a page where the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: sorry i cannot provide the link to the webpage. But it's similar to the text area that is used in the ideone.com.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem there?

Comment: Yes. i tried the same thing `browser.text_field(:id,"someid").set "1=1"` over there. Still itz not able to set the text.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
require "watir-webdriver"
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto "ideone.com"
browser.div(:id => "file_div").textarea.set "1=1"
```

Are you sure you need to set text in textarea? If you are dealing with wysiwyg editor, you probably need to use `send_keys`:

```
browser.pre.send_keys "1=1"
```

More information: http://watirwebdriver.com/wysiwyg-editors/

Comment: I am using watir 2.0.4. Sorry that i dint mention it earlier. And the above solution doesn't workout for me.
Yes i want to set text in the text area. The text area acts as a code highligter  for script and query expressions.

Comment: I tried `browser.send_keys "1=1"`. It only sends the keys "11" and ignores the "=" symbol.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to send keys on proper element. In my case, after some experimentations, that was:

`<div class="redactor_text redactor_optional redactor_redactor redactor_editor" contenteditable="true" dir="ltr" style="min-height: 120px;"></div>`

Editor was defined with this html:

`<div class="redactor_box"><ul class="redactor_toolbar" id="redactor_toolbar_0"><li><a href="javascript:;" title="Bold" tabindex="-1" class="re-icon re-bold"></a></li><li><a href="javascript:;" title="Italic" tabindex="-1" class="re-icon re-italic"></a></li><li><a href="javascript:;" title="Underline" tabindex="-1" class="re-icon re-underline"></a></li><li><a href="javascript:;" title="Link" tabindex="-1" class="re-icon re-link"></a></li><li><a href="javascript:;" title="Superscript" tabindex="-1" class="re-icon re-superscript fa-redactor-btn"><i class="fa icon-superscript"></i></a></li><li><a href="javascript:;" title="Subscript" tabindex="-1" class="re-icon re-subscript fa-redactor-btn"><i class="fa icon-subscript"></i></a></li></ul><div class="redactor_text redactor_optional redactor_redactor redactor_editor" contenteditable="true" dir="ltr" style="min-height: 120px;"></div><textarea class="text optional redactor" data-limit="450" data-persist="garlic" data-min-height="120" name="lesson[intro]" id="lesson_intro" dir="ltr" style="display: none;"></textarea></div>`